# How to get the quantity of Physical constants?

Tags: units, physical-constants

I need to get the quantity of gravitational constant: `QuantityMagnitude[GravitationalConstant]` why this is not work? Already load the `PhysicalConstants` package.

Comment: `QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]]`

Comment: @RunnyKine Great!

Comment: you do not need to load the `PhysicalConstants` package

Comment: man its irritating the docs just say "physical constant functionality is built into mathematica" without providing any clue how to access. Even if you find the `Quantity` page it doesn't say anything about physical constants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]]
```

> 6.67*10^-11